# Combining two working .vbs files

Tags: vbscript

So I have two working .vbs scripts do two different things, one removes the read-only attribute in a file, and the other removes all files with ".v" extension. Both work when a folder is dropped on to the script.

I tried combining them, but with my limited knowledge I get a bunch of errors.

First code:

```
   Option Explicit 
Sub main()

Dim ArgCount
Dim filExt
ArgCount = WScript.Arguments.Count
Select Case  ArgCount   
    Case 1 'Check the count of arguments
        Dim FSO,Path,File,Num_1,Num_2
        Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
        Path = WScript.Arguments(0)
        If FSO.FileExists(Path) Then
            Set File = FSO.GetFile(path)
            If  (File.Attributes Mod 2) = 1 Then  'Check if the Read-Only is selected, and remove it.
                File.Attributes = File.Attributes-1 
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
                    MsgBox "Error :" & Path &" "& Err.Description
                Else 
                    MsgBox "Fjernelse fuldført"
                End If 

            Else 
                MsgBox "The Read-Only attribute of file is not selected"
            End If 
        Else 
            RemoveSubFolder Path,Num_1,Num_2 
            MsgBox Num_2 & " filer fuldført" & ", " & Num_1 & " filer fejlet"
        End If 
    Case Else 
        MsgBox "Træk mappen oven på denne fil"
End Select 
End Sub 

'This function is to remove the Read-Only of all files in a folder and its subfolder
Function RemoveSubFolder(FolderPath,Num_1,Num_2)

    Dim FSObject,Folder
    Dim subFolder,File
    Num_1 = 0
    Num_2 = 0
    Set FSObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
    Set Folder = FSObject.GetFolder(FolderPath) 
    For Each  subFolder In Folder.SubFolders 'Loop the subfolder in the folder
        FolderPath = subFolder.Path 
        RemoveSubFolder FolderPath,Num_1,Num_2
    Next 
    For Each  File In Folder.Files 'Remove the Read-Only attribute of files in the folder
        If  (File.Attributes Mod 2) = 1 Then 
            File.Attributes = File.Attributes-1 
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
                MsgBox  "Error :" & File.Path &" "& Err.Description
                Num_1 = Num_1 + 1
            Else 
                Num_2 = Num_2 + 1 
            End If 
        End If 
        Err.Clear 
    Next 




    Set FSObject = Nothing 


    End Function 

Call main
```

The second code is this:

```
    Option Explicit

Dim FSObject, Folder, File, subFolder
Set FSObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Get the folder dropped onto our script...
    Folder = WScript.Arguments(0)

' Recursively check each file with the folder and its subfolders...
DoFolder Folder

Sub DoFolder(Folder)

    ' Check each file...
    For Each File In FSObject.GetFolder(Folder).Files
       If Right(File.name, 2) = ".v" Then
        FSObject.DeleteFile(Folder & "\" & File.name)
        End If
    Next

    ' Recursively check each subfolder...
    For Each subFolder In FSObject.GetFolder(Folder).SubFolders
        DoFolder subFolder.Path
    Next

End Sub
```

Now, I tried combining them, but get a Syntax error on line 34

```
     Option Explicit 
Sub main()

Dim ArgCount
Dim filExt
ArgCount = WScript.Arguments.Count
Select Case  ArgCount   
    Case 1 'Check the count of arguments
        Dim FSO,Path,File,Num_1,Num_2
        Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
        Path = WScript.Arguments(0)
        If FSO.FileExists(Path) Then
            Set File = FSO.GetFile(path)
            If  (File.Attributes Mod 2) = 1 Then  'Check if the Read-Only is selected, and remove it.
                File.Attributes = File.Attributes-1 
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
                    MsgBox "Error :" & Path &" "& Err.Description
                Else 
                    MsgBox "Fjernelse fuldført"
                End If 

            Else 
                MsgBox "The Read-Only attribute of file is not selected"
            End If 
        Else 
            RemoveSubFolder Path,Num_1,Num_2 
            MsgBox Num_2 & " filer fuldført" & ", " & Num_1 & " filer fejlet"
        End If 
    Case Else 
        MsgBox "Træk mappen oven på denne fil"
End Select 

'This function is to remove the Read-Only of all files in a folder and its subfolder
Function RemoveSubFolder(FolderPath,Num_1,Num_2)

    Dim FSObject,Folder
    Dim subFolder,File
    Num_1 = 0
    Num_2 = 0
    Set FSObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
    Set Folder = FSObject.GetFolder(FolderPath) 
    For Each  subFolder In Folder.SubFolders 'Loop the subfolder in the folder
        FolderPath = subFolder.Path 
        RemoveSubFolder FolderPath,Num_1,Num_2
    Next 
    For Each  File In Folder.Files 'Remove the Read-Only attribute of files in the folder
        If  (File.Attributes Mod 2) = 1 Then 
            File.Attributes = File.Attributes-1 
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
                MsgBox  "Error :" & File.Path &" "& Err.Description
                Num_1 = Num_1 + 1
            Else 
                Num_2 = Num_2 + 1 
            End If 
        End If 
        Err.Clear 
    Next 

' Recursively check each file with the folder and its subfolders...
DoFolder Folder

Sub DoFolder(Folder)

    ' Check each file...
    For Each File In FSObject.GetFolder(Folder).Files
       If Right(File.name, 2) = ".v" Then
        FSObject.DeleteFile(Folder & "\" & File.name)
        End If
    Next

    ' Recursively check each subfolder...
    For Each subFolder In FSObject.GetFolder(Folder).SubFolders
        DoFolder subFolder.Path
    Next

End Sub


    Set FSObject = Nothing 


    End Function 

Call main
```

They just don't work together, so how would I go about combining them?

UPDATE: I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPGrg.png) error with this code:

```
    Option Explicit 
Sub main()

Dim ArgCount
Dim filExt
ArgCount = WScript.Arguments.Count
Select Case  ArgCount   
    Case 1 'Check the count of arguments
        Dim FSO,Path,File,Num_1,Num_2
        Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
        Path = WScript.Arguments(0)
        If FSO.FileExists(Path) Then
            Set File = FSO.GetFile(path)
            If  (File.Attributes Mod 2) = 1 Then  'Check if the Read-Only is selected, and remove it.
                File.Attributes = File.Attributes-1 
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
                    MsgBox "Error :" & Path &" "& Err.Description
                Else 
                    MsgBox "Fjernelse fuldført"
                End If 

            Else 
                MsgBox "The Read-Only attribute of file is not selected"
            End If 
        Else 
            RemoveSubFolder Path,Num_1,Num_2 
            MsgBox Num_2 & " filer fuldført" & ", " & Num_1 & " filer fejlet"
        End If 
    Case Else 
        MsgBox "Træk mappen oven på denne fil"
End Select 
End Sub
'This function is to remove the Read-Only of all files in a folder and its subfolder
Function RemoveSubFolder(FolderPath,Num_1,Num_2)

    Dim FSObject,Folder
    Dim subFolder,File
    Num_1 = 0
    Num_2 = 0
    Set FSObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
    Set Folder = FSObject.GetFolder(FolderPath) 
    For Each  subFolder In Folder.SubFolders 'Loop the subfolder in the folder
        FolderPath = subFolder.Path 
        RemoveSubFolder FolderPath,Num_1,Num_2
    Next 
    For Each  File In Folder.Files 'Remove the Read-Only attribute of files in the folder
        If  (File.Attributes Mod 2) = 1 Then 
            File.Attributes = File.Attributes-1 
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
                MsgBox  "Error :" & File.Path &" "& Err.Description
                Num_1 = Num_1 + 1
            Else 
                Num_2 = Num_2 + 1 
            End If 
        End If 
        Err.Clear 
    Next 

' Recursively check each file with the folder and its subfolders...
DoFolder Folder

Sub DoFolder(Folder)

    ' Check each file...
    For Each File In FSObject.GetFolder(Folder).Files
       If Right(File.name, 2) = ".v" Then
        FSObject.DeleteFile(Folder & "\" & File.name)
        End If
    Next

    ' Recursively check each subfolder...
    For Each subFolder In FSObject.GetFolder(Folder).SubFolders
        DoFolder subFolder.Path
    Next

End Sub


    Set FSObject = Nothing 


    End Function 

Call main
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
      Option Explicit 
Sub main()

Dim ArgCount
Dim filExt,Num_1,Num_2
ArgCount = WScript.Arguments.Count
Select Case  ArgCount   
    Case 1 'Check the count of arguments
        Dim FSO,Path,File,Num_1,Num_2
        Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
        Path = WScript.Arguments(0)
        If FSO.FileExists(Path) Then
            Set File = FSO.GetFile(path)
            If  (File.Attributes Mod 2) = 1 Then  'Check if the Read-Only is selected, and remove it.
                File.Attributes = File.Attributes-1 
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
                    MsgBox "Error :" & Path &" "& Err.Description
                Else 
                    MsgBox "Fjernelse fuldført"
                End If 

            Else 
                MsgBox "The Read-Only attribute of file is not selected"
            End If 
        Else 
            RemoveSubFolder Path,Num_1,Num_2 
            MsgBox Num_2 & " filer fuldført" & ", " & Num_1 & " filer fejlet"
        End If 
    Case Else 
        MsgBox "Træk mappen oven på denne fil"
End Select 
End Sub
'This function is to remove the Read-Only of all files in a folder and its subfolder


    Dim FSObject,Folder
    Dim subFolder,File
    Num_1 = 0
    Num_2 = 0
    Set FSObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
    Set Folder = FSObject.GetFolder(FolderPath) 
    For Each  subFolder In Folder.SubFolders 'Loop the subfolder in the folder
        FolderPath = subFolder.Path 
        RemoveSubFolder FolderPath,Num_1,Num_2
    Next 
    For Each  File In Folder.Files 'Remove the Read-Only attribute of files in the folder
        If  (File.Attributes Mod 2) = 1 Then 
            File.Attributes = File.Attributes-1 
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
                MsgBox  "Error :" & File.Path &" "& Err.Description
                Num_1 = Num_1 + 1
            Else 
                Num_2 = Num_2 + 1 
            End If 
        End If 
        Err.Clear 
    Next 

' Recursively check each file with the folder and its subfolders...
DoFolder Folder

Sub DoFolder(Folder)

    ' Check each file...
    For Each File In FSObject.GetFolder(Folder).Files
       If Right(File.name, 2) = ".v" Then
        FSObject.DeleteFile(Folder & "\" & File.name)
        End If
    Next

    ' Recursively check each subfolder...
    For Each subFolder In FSObject.GetFolder(Folder).SubFolders
        DoFolder subFolder.Path
    Next

End Sub

Function RemoveSubFolder(FolderPath, Num_1, Num_2)
    Set FSObject = Nothing 


    End Function 

Call main
```

I get this error now:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7WCA.png

EDIT: After removing Num_1 and Num_2 definition in line 9, I get this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7KXT.png

Comment: For help with combining several code fragments: show your attempt at combining them and the error(s) that gave you.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Done :)

Comment: You have skipped some declarations in your script combination. And you have some flow logic errors.

Comment: @MihaiAdrian What declarations are missing? They are declared further up.

Comment: You forgot to add the errors you were mentioning.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I have updated my post with a new attempt, and a new error.

Comment: Please do not paraphrase errors. Show the complete error message in your question. If necessary post it as a screenshot, although text form would be preferred.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Done, it is in Danish though...

Comment: If you properly indent your code you would notice that some of the code is not in a sub/function. That is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

VBScript doesn't allow nesting procedure or function defintions insode other procedures or functions. Move the definition of `DoFolder` outside the function `RemoveSubFolder`.

```
Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    'Check each file...
    For Each File In FSObject.GetFolder(Folder).Files
        If Right(File.Name, 2) = ".v" Then
            FSObject.DeleteFile(Folder & "\" & File.Name)
        End If
    Next

    'Recursively check each subfolder...
    For Each subFolder In FSObject.GetFolder(Folder).SubFolders
        DoFolder subFolder.Path
    Next
End Sub

Function RemoveSubFolder(FolderPath, Num_1, Num_2)
    ...
End Function
```

Comment: if I do that, and define Num_1 and Num_2 in the top, I get this error https://i.imgur.com/TDfgvLI.png translating to The name is redefined.

Comment: @LTC The error says you're re-defining the variable `Num_1`. The code you claim to have doesn't do that. Please update your question with your actual code.

Comment: You're defining both variables `Num_1` and `Num_2` in the lines 4 and 9. Each variable must be defined only once.

Comment: I get this error, after removing the Num_1 and Num_2 definition in line 9 
https://i.imgur.com/uEfkGCh.png

Comment: Final response, because this is not a live debugging session. You moved the code from your function `RemoveSubFolder` to the global scope. Please go find a VBScript tutorial, because you clearly have no idea what you're doing.